# My First Math Riddle

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Okay, so I write a lot of Riley and story riddles; however, I've noticed that I like the mathematical riddles too! I decided to write one, and I hope you all enjoy it. A few rules:

- No rotation.
- No duplication.
- No combination.
- No rounding.
- No computers.

---

### **Good luck to all of you!**

---

You are given the following set of numbers: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. Inject these numbers into the following equation to create a true statement.

$$\frac{a - b + c / de} {6} = \frac{6}{f}$$

Comment: If you want, you can write `$\cdot$` or `$\times$` to respectively generate $\cdot$ or $\times$ for multiplication :)

Comment: Does $c/de$ mean (1) $c/(d\cdot e)$, (2) $(c/d)\cdot e$, or (3) $c$ divided by the two-digit number given by $de$?

Comment: Multiply d by e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's:

> $(6-4+5/1*2)/6)$ = $(6/3)$

Comment: wow 3 answers at basically the same time

Answer (score 7):

> $\frac{6 - 4 + 5 / 1 * 2} {6} = \frac{6}{3}$

Answer (score 6):

> $\frac{1 - 2 + 6/3*5}{6} = \frac{6}{4} = \frac{3}{2} = 1.5$

So

> $a=1, b=2, c=6, d=3, e=5, f=4$

Edit: The rules say no computers and I didn't use a computer to get the first answer but I did use one to get these other answers:

> $\frac{1 - 2 + 5/3*6}{6} = \frac{6}{4}, \frac{1 - 4 + 5/2*6}{6} = \frac{6}{3}, \frac{1 - 4 + 6/2*5}{6} = \frac{6}{3}, \frac{3 - 5 + 2/1*4}{6} = \frac{6}{6}, \frac{3 - 5 + 4/1*2}{6} = \frac{6}{6}, \frac{6 - 4 + 2/1*5}{6} = \frac{6}{3}, \frac{6 - 4 + 5/1*2}{6} = \frac{6}{3}$

These are all the solutions I believe.